# "Error when reading ./.erlang.cookie: eacces" while enabling rabbitmq plugin

Tags: debian, kali-linux, rabbitmq, erlang

I installed rabbitmq on kali linux. I started the service

```
 sudo systemctl start rabbitmq-server
```

Then I tried to enable the management plugin

```
 rabbitmq-plugins enable rabbitmq_management
```

But I am getting this error:

```
 Error when reading ./.erlang.cookie: eacces
```

Looks like I am not not authorized to read from the cookie. How can I resolve this?

I tried this

```
sudo chmod 600 ./.erlang.cookie
```

and

```
sudo chmod 600 /var/lib/rabbitmq/.erlang.cookie
```

but did not help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to copy the `.erlang.cookie` file to `$HOME` directory.

```
sudo cp /var/lib/rabbitmq/.erlang.cookie $HOME
```

then i had to give read access to the file

```
 sudo chmod +r ./.erlang.cookie
```

finally

```
sudo rabbitmq-plugins enable rabbitmq_management
```

Comment: It should work if you skip the path change and permissions update, so just do `sudo rabbitmq-plugins enable rabbitmq_management`